# Arduino State Machine issue with a state machine

Tags: c, arduino

So I wanted to make a state machine, that gets an input letter from the user and outputs the morsecode
using a LED. I used a switch, but for some reason it doesn't want to work. It only worked for
letter a, when i added another letter it stop working.

I used 3 functions (dot, line and pause) and combined them for the blinking of the LED. We are not allowed to use the "delay()" in our school so i made a timer.

````
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STATUS_IDLE (0)
#define STATUS_A (1)
#define STATUS_B (2)


// Global Variables
unsigned char status;
unsigned long int t_ref; // Reference time
unsigned char last_PINB;
unsigned char mainStatus;
// define inputs and outputs

#define OUTPUT_H1_LAMPE (PC0)

// whenever a variable is used by both, Interrupt and main programm we
// need to tell the compiler about it ==> volatile
volatile unsigned long int millisekunden; // milli seconds timer
unsigned long int last_msg;               //
char buffer[128];
unsigned int c;
unsigned int counter;

void setup() {
  DDRC |= (1 << OUTPUT_H1_LAMPE);

  // Timer 0 konfigurieren
  TCCR0A = (1 << WGM01);               // CTC Modus
  TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00); // Prescaler 64
  // ((16000000/64)/1000) = 25
  OCR0A = 250;

  // Compare Interrupt erlauben
  TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

int last_char = -1;

void dot() {
  while (millisekunden - t_ref <= 300) {
    if (millisekunden - t_ref > 300) {
      t_ref = millisekunden;
      break;
    }
    PORTC |= (1 << OUTPUT_H1_LAMPE);
  }

}

void line() {
  while (millisekunden - t_ref <= 900) {
    if (millisekunden - t_ref > 900) {
      t_ref = millisekunden;
      break;
    }
    PORTC |= (1 << OUTPUT_H1_LAMPE);
  }
}
void pause() {
  while (millisekunden - t_ref <= 300) {
    if (millisekunden - t_ref > 300) {
      t_ref = millisekunden;
      break;
    }
    PORTC &= ~(1 << OUTPUT_H1_LAMPE);
  }

}



void loop() {

  if (millisekunden - last_msg >=1000) {
    sprintf(buffer, "t=[%lu] state=[%d] PORTC=[%2.2x] t_ref=[%lu]",
            millisekunden, mainStatus, PORTC, t_ref);
    Serial.println(buffer);
    last_msg = millisekunden;
  }


  // user input => get key ...
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    last_char = Serial.read(); // Read a character
    sprintf(buffer, "you have pressed the [%c]-key", (char)last_char);
    Serial.println(buffer);
  }
  if (tolower(last_char) == 'a') {
    t_ref = millisekunden;
    mainStatus = STATUS_A;
    last_char = -1;
  }

  if (tolower(last_char) == 'b') {
    t_ref = millisekunden;
    mainStatus = STATUS_B;
    last_char = -1;
  }

 
  switch (mainStatus) {

    case STATUS_IDLE:
      PORTC &= ~(1 << OUTPUT_H1_LAMPE);
      break;
    case STATUS_A:
      dot();
      pause();
      line();
      mainStatus = STATUS_IDLE;
      break;
    case STATUS_B:
      line();
      pause();
      dot();
      pause();
      dot();
      pause();
      dot();
      mainStatus = STATUS_IDLE;
      break;

  }

}

// Timer-Interrupt-Routine
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
  millisekunden++;
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot could be said about this code.  I really don't understand why you're doing things quite the way you are.  But, if I go for the smallest change that would make your code work, it's as follows.

You have this sort of pattern repeated in your `dot`, `line`, `pause`:

```cpp
while (millisekunden - t_ref <= 300) {
  if (millisekunden - t_ref > 300) {
    t_ref = millisekunden;
    break;
  }
  PORTC |= (1 << OUTPUT_H1_LAMPE);
}
```

I've taken `dot` for the above.  Occasionally what will happen is `millisekunden - t_ref <= 300` will be false, without `millisekunden - t_ref > 300` ever having been true.  Again, I don't understand why you're doing it this way.  But, the end result is that sometimes your loop exits having executed `t_ref = millisekunden` and sometimes it exits without having done that.

If you change these to:

```cpp
while (millisekunden - t_ref <= 300) {
  PORTC |= (1 << OUTPUT_H1_LAMPE);
}
t_ref = millisekunden;
```

With that arrangement, your update of `t_ref` will always occur when the loop exits, and the program behaves more or less the way I'd expect, hopefully the way you expect.

It doesn't really make sense to keep setting the bit in `PORTC` either, but as I said, smallest change.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know my code isnt that good im still a beginner but im learning. Thanks again , you solved my problem! :)